# how do i count the number of elements in array when elements are objects in BigQuery StandardSql

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following json

```
{
  "CustomerId": "B0001",
  "Items": [
    {
      "ItemId": "00001",
      "ItemName": "Banana"
    },
    {
      "ItemId": "00001",
      "ItemName": "Orange"
    },
    {
      "ItemId": "00001",
      "ItemName": "apple"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to count the number of items in thes case the column should return 3
i have tried

```
select ARRAY_LENGTH(Items) as Number_of_items2
```

but this obviously throws error on bigquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming it's actually stored as a JSON string, you can try:

```
select ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(Items, '},')) as Number_of_items2
FROM dataset.table
```

This relies on the specific format of the JSON, but if you need more advanced processing logic, you can use a [JavaScript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#external-udf-structure).